# Не удается найти элемент после Ajax запроса

Tags: jquery

Почему-то не получается найти элемент по id для блока `html`, который формируется и приходит от сервера посредством Ajax запроса. В браузере появляется блок выбора `select`, но `$("#test").on('change', function()` его не видит.

Примечательно то, что при использовании этого кода без Ajax на html странице все работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чем проблема.

```js
$("#test").on('change', function() {
    b = $(this).val();
    console.log(b);
});
```

```html
<select id="test">
    <option>Выберите значение</option> 
    <option value="1">Первый элемент</option>    
    <option value="2">Второй элемент</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `$('body').on('change', '#test', function() {});`

Comment: @Pavel, как принятый ответ относится к проблеме описанной в вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно `$('#u_money_s').html(html);` она даст вывести вам ответ с тегами html

```
$('#u_money').submit(function(){
  var str = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"inc/adm.php",
    data:str,
    success:function(html){
      $('#u_money_s').html(html);
    }

});
return false;
});
```